# How to change tab bar highlighted color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Flutter Tab Color]
***Note***:
Solution from stackoverflow about this question not solved my issue

My full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookingHistory extends StatefulWidget {
  BookingHistory({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookingHistoryState createState() => _BookingHistoryState();
}

class _BookingHistoryState extends State<BookingHistory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Scaffold(
            // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: AppBar(

              flexibleSpace: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TabBar(indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                      labelColor: Colors.red,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,

                        tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Completed",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Requested",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Accepted",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
                    ])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            body: TabBarView(children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("i am tab 1"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("i am tab 2"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("i am tab 3"),
                ),
              )
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**Answer** 
To make effecting   indicatorColor,labelColor or unselectedLabelColor we need wrap Widget with  Material Widget(Solution suggested by ***Ravinder Kumar***) or if we need only to change indicatorColor color then use `indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent` color with ending with name *Accent* (Solution suggested by ***Amazing Aidan***)

Comment: Bizarrely, changing the code to 

**indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent** 

works but not Colors.blue

Comment: Yes, it is working please add it as answer i will accept it

Comment: Like I edited in my answer, Not just `Colors.blueAccent` any color except blue is working. So that's why right now my approach is more correct for all colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bizarrely, changing the code to

```
indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent
```

works but not Colors.blue

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `TabBar` inside `Material` widget,

```
 Material(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    child:
                    TabBar(
                      indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                      labelColor: Colors.red,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,
.....
```

Output:

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
class BookingHistory extends StatefulWidget {
  BookingHistory({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookingHistoryState createState() => _BookingHistoryState();
}

class _BookingHistoryState extends State<BookingHistory> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Scaffold(
            // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: AppBar(

              flexibleSpace: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Material(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    child:
                    TabBar(
                      indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                      labelColor: Colors.red,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,

                        tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Completed",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Requested",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Accepted",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]))

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            body: TabBarView(children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("i am tab 1"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("i am tab 2"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("i am tab 3"),
                ),
              )
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** strangely any colors other than seems to work, for example use `indicatorColor: Colors.black,`

Comment: Thank you for your support and your answer also working

Answer (score 0):

The `Container` in the `AppBar` is unncessary, instead directly set `backgroundColor: Colors.green` in `AppBar`.

And in the `TabBar` set `indicatorColor`, `labelColor`, `unselectedLabelColor` properly.

In each `Tab` you don't need to specify `TextStyle`. It will override `labelColor` and `unselectedLabelColor` from the `TabBar`.

```
AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  flexibleSpace: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          labelColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white70,
          tabs: [
            Tab(child: Text("Completed")),
            Tab(child: Text("Requested")),
            Tab(child: Text("Accepted"))
          ])
    ],
  ),
)
```